# What command is used in mysql to look at the table and give tips?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I seem to remember that there is a command to look at a mysql table and let you know things like maximum size of strings and integers and such so you can optimize the size of your index/table.

Do you know what that command is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM `table`
PROCEDURE ANALYSE ( )
```

does what you want